# How to write a for-loop to iterate through the list and print the data of every other element of the list

Tags: c++, c++11

Our professor assigned us a question :
Assume you are given a pointer to the head of an existing list (named head). The nodes of the linked-list are of type struct Node (as defined on display 13.7 on page 754). Write a for-loop to iterate through the list and print the data of every other element of the list (starting with the first element).

I have no idea, please help me with that, thanks!

Comment: Have you tried anything yourself? Which part of what you've tried is giving you trouble?

Comment: The best way to handle practically any linked list question is to draw the sucker out with pen on paper.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming each Node has a data member and a pointer/reference to the next node, you can do a while loop like you would normally do, but only output on odd or even iterations, so your code could look something like:

```
for(Node* myList = head, int i = 0; myList != nullptr; myList = myList->next, ++i)
{
    if(i % 2) == 0)
    {
        std::cout << myList->data << std::endl;
    }
}
```

All this does is to go through the list and see if `i` is even or not, and if it is, output the data in the current node. When it hits a `nullptr`, that is the end of the list. The reason you can't do `myList = myList->next->next` is that you don't want to try to step past the end of the list and access memory that wasn't given to you, or try to dereference a null pointer
You could just as easily do `if((i % 0) == 1)` also to get the odd set of every other Node.

Answer (score 0):

The Node type usually has a Node type attribute associated with it. This is in turn known as the link which can let you traverse the list. So for example if you have the pointer to the first node, then that node object has a field that is the next node. So you can use this in a for loop to go from node to node. Within this loop you obviously would need to not count every other node and then it is just a matter of a print statement during every other node. You could accomplish this by having a current node field and then just updating where you are until you have reached a node with a null link or you have reached then end of the chain if you know the size.
[This link may help you with the syntax and understanding pointers.](http://cs.stmarys.ca/~porter/csc/common_341_342/notes/linked_nodes.html)